# Where is index.g.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to work through this tutorial, [ASP.Net Core Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio), but (often) when I build the solution, I get a `CS0234` error stating that a namespace is missing from file `Index.g.cshtml.cd`, but where does this file exist?

I have tried

1. All the build/clean/rebuild solution options.
2. I have restarted Visual Studio
3. I have deleted the DEBUG files and restarted VS and FINALLY
4. I have restarted my PC.
   The ONLY solution that seems to work, is to delete the entire solution/project and start again.

Surely there must be a fix for this?
Can you assist?

Answer (score 40):

If an error says a using directive or namespace is missing from `xxx.g.cshtml.cs`, that usually means, that there is a directive directly in the view (`.cshtml` or `.vbhtml`), that the compiler cannot resolve.

In my case I had  the following statement in a partial view:

```
@inject UserManager<AppUser> UserManager
```

I then went along and refactored the AppUser class from the web application `Namespace.Web.AppUser` into `Namespace.Entities.AppUser`, which then was causing that error.

There are different ways to resolve this.
The easiest way is to use a fully qualified type namespace:

```
@inject UserManager<Namespace.Entities.AppUser> UserManager
```

And do not forget to add a reference to the other project, if it is in another project.
Or: add a using statement:

```
@using Namespace.Entities;
```

Or: Add the using statement above to your `~\Views\_ViewStart.cshtml`. This will make that class available in all views.

Comment: It might also be a strongly-typed view:  @model Namespace.Entity

Comment: @ZackPeterson, yes - absolutely. The key takeaway really just is, you got a compile time error directly in your view, and there is no .g.cshtml file, that you can check.

Comment: Hello there, I did all of this (the bottom added the using the namespace.entities) and I still get this error but only when I'm using the build+IntelliSense. It doesn't show up when I switch it just to Build or IntelliSense separately. I know this is an old answer but I hope you see this. It only gives me the error for the debug files in the obj folder though, not the regular view files

Comment: @ZackPeterson, This resolved my issue. I had changed the models name for the project to switch from a Blazor pages to an MVC style project. I wanted to use the original namespace. The Views folder had an @ Model directive that was still using the old namespace and renaming that was enough to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question - this is exactly what was going on in my project! Really appreciate your help :-)

Answer (score 14):

I landed here with the same errors with Visual Studio 2019 16.2.2. For me, I had changed the name of some of the models and rather than picking up the error in the actual views which were using the models, the error showed in page.g.cshtml rather than page.cshtml.

So, my solution was rather simple. If the error was in page.g.cshtml, ignore the g, go to the view page.cshtml, update the model name to the correct name, rebuild and errors gone.

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution for my case!

Answer (score 5):

right click your project and open folder in Explorer. Then search for "Index.g.cshtml.cs" 
Then delete the file search results

Make sure your Index.cshtml is referencing the correct model.

Answer (score 3):

Recently I have faced the same issue,

Try the following simple method

1. copy the error and paste it in the notepad. There you can able to see the original root cause path of the error file, e.g `'YourProjectFolder'\obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\Razor\Views\'View Name'\index.g.cshtml.cs`
2. Locate the file, if the error really persists refer the correct namespace in your index.cshtml file else delete the file and rebuild.
3. Also check you have any duplicate file and which was excluded from the project. If it is exists delete the file too
4. Now clean and rebuild the project. (You may need to clean, close VS, rebuild)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question and elaborate (1) why your recipe works and (2) what you exactly mean by the last point. I guess it involves a `npm cache clean` or something

Comment: @B--rian My last point was not pointing towards npm cache clean, I meant project clean and rebuild option. Moreover as ImConfused replied below, this can't be a VS bug. ImConfused might have looked into the error details clearly. VS tells you about the error clearly.

Answer (score 2):

If your solutions keeps failing because of those .g .cs files, it could be because you forgot to update the namespace of a class that you may have moved, in the actual cshtml file (example via an injection of the said namespace).

This is what solved the issue for me:
https://til.secretgeek.net/.net_core_MVC/error_in_g_cs.html

Answer (score 2):

May be my answer is something late, but hopefully it will help someone:
I have faced the dame issue because I have changed the Project name and later I tried to change the namespaces inside controllers and models, then I found out there is a direct mentioning of the namespace inside (**Pages/_ViewImports.cshtml**) from there I updated them to match the namespace used inside my models and the issues gone. [ViewImportsImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFX1g.png)

Now my ViewImports.cshtml content looks as follows:
[ViewsImport.cshtml content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT30J.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can try below solution

1. Go to C:\Temp\msbuild 
   2.There you would find folder with your project name and inside those folder you find these files as shown in below image[image]
2. Try to delete those files and rebuild your solution that might help you

Comment: Thanks....but I cant find a Temp folder on C:\. I have 'unhidden' folders that should be hidden.   There is a Temp folder in C:\Windows, but it does not contain any of the files that you show here.

Comment: Sorry for late reply got busy with work . You can try following                               1. Search for  %temp% in our system or directly search "Index.g.cshtml.cd" on your system                                                                                                  2.Or double click on that error that opens the file in Visual Studio, Do a right click and click on open the file location

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no real answer to this question. 
It turns out that the file is create inside the DEBUG folder.
However, after deleting the Debug folder, I was still getting the error.
So it must be a VS bug?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean all the obj folders in all of your projects and build again. This is part of the code that is generated by the compiler, sometimes it is not synchronized with the view itself, even Rebuild that should clean everything doesn't work. Do it manually. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It's Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design Package issue.

I tried with 2.2 version in my VS2017 which does not support this and gives "*.g.cshtml not found*" in obj directory.

I solved issue as below:

- I downgraded ASP.NET Core version of my project 2.2 to 2.1
- Changes done in *startup.cs*:

  1. CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2 to CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1
  2. Change all dll of Nuget packages to 2_1 supportive dll
  3. SDK make sure its 2.1.x

and issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Add full namespace in _ViewImports

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http