# CS0234 The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace in ASP.NET Core 7 MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

I built a CRUD operation in ASP.NET Core 7.0 MVC using a modal popup in Visual Studio 2022.

The initial class model was called Item:

```cs
namespace Mvc1.Models
{
    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        [Precision(10, 2)]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Data Context **Mvc1Context** contains definitions for **Items**:

```cs
public class Mvc1Context : DbContext
{
    public Mvc1Context (DbContextOptions<Mvc1Context> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        foreach (var property in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
            .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
            .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(decimal) || p.ClrType == typeof(decimal?)))
        {
            property.SetPrecision(10);
            property.SetScale(2);
        }
    }

    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; } = default!;

}
```

I built the **ItemsController**

```cs
namespace Mvc1.Controllers
{
    public class ItemsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly Mvc1Context _context;

        public ItemsController(Mvc1Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Items
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
              return _context.Items != null ? 
                          View(await _context.Items.ToListAsync()) :
                          Problem("Entity set 'Mvc1Context.Item'  is null.");
        }

        // GET: Items/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Items == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var item = await _context.Items
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(item);
        }

        // GET: Items/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Items/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,Price")] Item item)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(item);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(item);
        }

        // GET: Items/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Items == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var item = await _context.Items.FindAsync(id);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(item);
        }

        // POST: Items/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Name,Price")] Item item)
        {
            if (id != item.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(item);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!ItemExists(item.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(item);
        }

        // GET: Items/Delete/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null || _context.Items == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var item = await _context.Items
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(item);
        }

        // POST: Items/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            if (_context.Items == null)
            {
                return Problem("Entity set 'Mvc1Context.Item'  is null.");
            }
            var item = await _context.Items.FindAsync(id);
            if (item != null)
            {
                _context.Items.Remove(item);
            }
            
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool ItemExists(int id)
        {
          return (_context.Items?.Any(e => e.Id == id)).GetValueOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I created the **Views**. Here is the **Index.cshtml** file:

```html
@model IEnumerable<Mvc1.Models.Item>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

From the Package Manager Console, I added migration:

> `PM> Add-Migration "Initial Migration"`

The program ran fine.

I looked at the code and noticed that the class **Item** might be better named **Items**, so I selected **Item** and used Visual Studio 2022's Rename key combination "CTRL+R, CTRL+R" to rename the class.

Now, it doesn't compile anymore. I removed migration via the PM Console, but I can't add migration again because the project does not build (VS2022 wants to build before adding migration).

My errors are:

> CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Item' does not exist in the namespace 'Mvc1.Models' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I get this 10 times, and they are all in files that are not in my project:

- `Views_Items_Create_cshtml.g.cs    Line 32`
- `Views_Items_Create_cshtml.g.cs    Line 299`
- `Views_Items_Delete_cshtml.g.cs    Line 32`
- `Views_Items_Delete_cshtml.g.cs    Line 184`
- `Views_Items_Details_cshtml.g.cs   Line 32`
- `Views_Items_Details_cshtml.g.cs   Line 170`
- `Views_Items_Edit_cshtml.g.cs      Line 32`
- `Views_Items_Edit_cshtml.g.cs      Line 323`
- `Views_Items_Index_cshtml.g.cs     Line 32`
- `Views_Items_Index_cshtml.g.cs     Line 250`

These look like generated files that I need to edit or delete, but I can't find them.

A similar question:

[Where is index.g.cshtml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52463031/22019322)

Lots of solutions about deleting the temp files, checking the Views for the files `Create.cshtml`, `Delete.cshtml`, `Details.cshtml`, `Delete.cshtml`, `Edit.cshtml`, and `Index.cshtml` - the model names are defined there. I even tried renaming **Item** in these files to **Items**, but the error just changes to *The type or namespace name 'Items' does not exist*.

I've also rebooted three (3) times.

I feel like the only solution is to ditch this project and restart it, but I'd rather know how to fix it because it might happen again.

Does anyone know where these files are, or how I can fix this problem?

Comment: You need to rename Item to Items in the .cshtml files e.g. Views_Items_Index.cshtml. or change it back to Item in c;#.

Comment: @Stewart when I do that, then the compiler tells me `The type or namespace name 'Items' does not exist in the namespace 'Mvc1.Models'`

Comment: You can try to add `<PropertyGroup>
    <EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>   
</PropertyGroup>` in your `.csproj` file then The file will by default go to `obj\debug\net6.0\generated\...`